# TL-WN722N Not working on laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, broadcom

I bought WiFi adaptor (TL-WN722N) for my laptop (which has built in WiFi). Then I followed multiple articles on how to install driver for that adaptor but it still isn't working. But when I type `lsusb` command I have new empty line:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:010c  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04d9:1503 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is the Broadcom built-in WiFi was interfering with my TP-Link adaptor?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that the any other wireless network adapter interferes with the external TP-Link adapter.

Even though this answers your literal question I don't think that it's really useful to you. If you'd like to know how to get either of the network adapters to work please [open a new question](/questions/ask) and ask for it explicitly. It helps if you include the output of the [network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) in your question.